# Android Alarm app where alarms can be set with a web interface

Tags: android, alarm-clock

Is there an alarm app in Android that allows Alarms to be set from a web interface? I am extremely clumsy when typing on the phone and often mistype the alarm time or date. But I often have a need for persistent alarms for some tasks and I am tired of setting alarm in the stock Alarm application or even the Time.ly app and getting it wrong half the time.

Comment: Paid apps are perfectly acceptable

Comment: Not sure if it's considered as an answer since I think it's more than a workaround: calendar web apps *might* be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this feature.

I wasn't able to find even a third-party app that would offer Web UI for managing my alarms in addition to the app.

Even excellent tools such as [Alarmy](https://alar.my/) doesn't offer this functionality.

I need it because I want to to manage my alarms from the convenience of my desk computer easily for having a better *sleep management* and setting up my weekly routines.

I've already send numerous feedbacks such as the one on [Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock&hl=en_US) app's Google Play page to Google to enable such experience on the built in Clock app.

So from my experience and research so far, I could say **there's no such thing** (yet), unfortunately.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66463)

Comment: Yes, I know, but there might not be an answer; I just wanted to document my experience. Where else can I do so if that's not a proper place? (The comment field was too short for it)